# How to update a variable inside forEach function? Getting Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach

```
export class myclass implements OnInit {
    private outagesList;
    private outageArray;

    constructor(private outages: OutagesService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.outages.getOutagesList().subscribe((data) => {
            this.outagesList = data;
            this.outagesList.forEach( function (arrayItem)  
            {             
              this.outageArray.push(arrayItem["title"]);          
            });
        )
}
```

If i try to push the data into outageArray it is throwing  `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'outageArray' of undefined`

How can i avoid this error? I need to access this outageArray value to html.

Comment: `this.outagesList.forEach((arrayItem) => { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an arrow function

```
this.outagesList.forEach((arrayItem) => {
  this.outageArray.push(arrayItem["title"]);         
});
```

Comment: This question has already been answered hundreds of times. Do we need one more answer?

Answer (score -1):

Once you are using post-ES6 Javascript, functions like `forEach` are not likely to be your best solution. The easiest way to do this is with a `for..of` loop:

```
this.outages.getOutagesList().subscribe((data) => {
    this.outagesList = data;
    for (let arrayItem of this.outagesList)
    {             
      this.outageArray.push(arrayItem.title);          
    });
)
```